Path Gradient categorising sections with QGIS
Using height data and a paths layer I am wanting to identify gradients over that pathway and categorise it, so 0-5% easy, 5-8% moderate and over 8% gradient hard.
I've looked at the plug in "road slope" and it works for sections depending on how many metres I set it too but this is really too broad as within that there could be a steep part and it is just averaging it out. Really I want to highlight and identify sections of the path that would be easy, med or hard
